# How to tabulate column data in Python with tabulate

Tags: python

The tabulate module in python seems to favor processing rows:

```py
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> col0 = ["age","sex","location"]
>>> col1 = ["twenty", "male", "mars"]
>>> print(tabulate([col0,col1]))
------  ----  --------
age     sex   location
twenty  male  mars
------  ----  --------
```

Since I have data arranged in columns, I want to see:

```py
--------  ------
age       twenty
sex       male
location  mars
--------  ------
```

How can I do this without copying the data around?

I have a solution that makes a wasteful copy before feeding the data to tabulate

Answer (score 1):

By using zip to combine the two lists into list of lists this can be done.

```py
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> col0 = ["age","sex","location"]
>>> col1 = ["twenty", "male", "mars"]
>>> print(tabulate(list(zip(col0,col1))))
--------  ------
age       twenty
sex       male
location  mars
--------  ------
```